# Spring XSD's access error

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-mvc, xsd

I'm trying to run a system left by an ex-employee here in my job, but I'm having problems to do it.

If the XSD runs by remote access:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
```

It gives an not found exception:

```
Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

And if the XSD runs by local access:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           classpath:org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
           classpath:org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool
           classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd">
```

It gives this exception:

```
C:\Users\claudiomazur>java -jar c:\temp\fin\c.jar  
0 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext  - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@4fa52fdf: startup date [Thu Sep 06  
11:22:59 BRT 2012]; root of context hierarchy  
45 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [context.xml]  
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for  
XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]  
Offending resource: class path resource [context.xml]  

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
```

Some idea to solve this problem?

Big hug!!

Comment: what xml parser uses in application?

Comment: I don't have idea about this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Spring XDSs are defined and shipped with the Spring jars! For Example the `spring-context.jar` contains the `spring-context-3.0.xsd`. (see `spring-context.jar`/META-INF/spring.schema)

So check that you have this jar in your project.

So what you called "remote" is not really remote! And I have never see what you called "local access", so I would try to check why the "remote" (that is not remote) stuff works for all xsds but the spring-context.

---

If it is a desktop program and you use a single jar that contains all the other exploded jars, then you need a to take care that the content of the single `spring.handlers` and `spring.schames` files from the different spring-xxx.jar is COMBINED in (two) "hunge" files. So that in the end this (two) files contains all the schema names and handler names.

Comment: I think yes, in this dependency:
`code`
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>`code`

Comment: @user1618606: I mean check REALLY! Check that this file is within the WAR deployed on your server

Comment: yes... it is on the full path: C:\Users\claudiomazur\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\3.0.6.RELEASE\spring-context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Check it in the WAR! It must be within the WAR file!

Comment: I have disabled all internet protections, and now it's accessing the xsd... But now it gives the last exception:
Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for  
XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]  
Offending resource: class path resource [context.xml]

Comment: @user1618606: Check if spring-context.jar is the WAR! It must be within the WAR file!

Comment: I extracted the .jar file built by Eclipse using winrar. There is no .jar file on the content, but the file spring-context-3.0.xsd is located on the path: ..\org\springframework\context\config

Comment: What are you doing? Your question is tagged with "spring-mvc", so I assume that you have an Web Project. Web Projects normaly produce WAR files (at least this are zip files). This war files normaly contains all the libarys that the application needs in the folder WEB-INF\lib.

Comment: @user1618606 I have an idea: does the war file contains no jars, but all the classes from the jars in the WEB-INF\classes folder?

Comment: @user1618606: nice picture, but what does it show, the WAR? -- What do you deploy to your server?

Comment: this is the jar decompressed... I access the it on the server by jnlp

Comment: user1618606: But I asked for the WAR! -- why do you not have a WAR?

Comment: well.. this is an desktop program... there is no war... =/

Comment: See my extended answer --- and next time please answer the questions correct. I asked you since 3 hours for the WAR and you never told that it is not a web app.

Comment: \o/ really sorry... I was reading war as jar... really sorry.
Well, I create a file spring.handlers and add http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context=org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler and http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx=org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler and it finally runs. Really thanks!!! PROBLEM SOLVED!!!

Answer (score 3):

Its true that the SPRING XSD's are shipped along with the jars.

The information where these XSD's are stored :

1. Lets say in the XML file, we have used beans namespace and we need to look into

   ```
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   ```
2. Please check the file "spring-schemas" spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar in META-INF folder.
   Sample context from this file should be:

   ```
   http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd 
   =org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.0.xsd

   http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
   =org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   ```
3. Thus

   ```
        http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  is mapped to      
        org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   ```

   in your jar

Answer (score 2):

try run wget http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd.

```
should be something like: wget http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
--2012-09-10 15:56:05--  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
Resolving www.springframework.org... 205.140.197.88
Connecting to www.springframework.org|205.140.197.88|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 19651 (19K) [text/xml]
Saving to: “spring-context-3.0.xsd”

100%[=====================================================================>] 19,651      24.6K/s   in 0.8s    

2012-09-10 15:56:06 (24.6 KB/s) - “spring-context-3.0.xsd” saved [19651/19651]
```

If you have a problem with getting xsd schema, it makes difficult to work with xml files inherited this schema.

In second case you simply don't have in classpath any of spring-*-3.0.xsd files.

Comment: @Ralph yes, you rigth. But described in question behavior isn't usual. Looks like parser don't uses what defined in meta-inf

Comment: Sorry my fault, I have not read your answer correct, I expected you suggest to check the xsd file.

Comment: I have disabled all internet protections, and now it's accessing the xsd... But now it gives the last exception:
Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for  
XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]  
Offending resource: class path resource [context.xml]

Comment: @user1618606 Looks like you put spring-context.jar not in WEB-INF/lib directory in resulted WAR file.

Comment: Yes, it definitly wrong. If resulted war file doesn't contain WEB-INF/lib folder, your build process is broken. Check any errors or warnings when you run build.

Comment: Cool, but from it i understand only two things: You using eclipse for build, and i'm very glad it's not my project.

Comment: this is the jar decompressed... I access the it on the server by jnlp