# springframework.org is down

Tags: java, spring, glassfish

I have a Java EE application on Glassfish 4 which uses org.springframework in maven. After rebooting the server, glassfish won't start and give the following error:

```
[2014-02-09T03:59:41.284+0900] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1391885981284] [levelValue: 900] [[
WELD-001210 Warning when validating file: (some_directory)/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/service-1.0/WEB-INF/beans.xml@29 against xsd. schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.]]

[2014-02-09T03:59:41.820+0900] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1391885981820] [levelValue: 900] [[
WELD-001208 Error when validating file:(some_directory)/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/service-1.0/WEB-INF/beans.xml@38 against xsd. src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'beans:identifiedType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.]]
```

It turned out that http://springframework.org is offline, and as the result I am not able to boot glassfish because the following file is missing:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
```

It seems that I have to wait springframework.org to come back until I can start my Glassfish server.
I am wondering is there any way to prevent this from happening in the future?

For example, is there any way to save all needed files from springframework.org to local directory so that my website will not be broken because springframework.org is down?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350673/spring-xsds-access-error

Comment: thx for your reply, @Evgeni! I have two EE apps, one using SpringFrameworks 3.2.3, and the other one using 3.2.7. I changed both of them to 3.2.7, and it works now.